# Возможно ли изменить атрибут style у div блока при выполнении условия в MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, есть некий div блок, у которого задан атрибут style, я хочу менять этот стайл в зависимости от значения, которое придет с контроллера, например:

```
@if(value = 30)
{
<div style=margin-left: 30px">...</div>
}
else
{
<div style=margin-left: 0px">...</div>
}
```

как вы наверное понимаете, блок div содержит внутри довольно много кода и не охота было было бы его дублировать, как можно поступить в данном случаи? Пробовал через тернарный оператор, но на выходе всегда была ошибка

Comment: Вычисли только то, что будет меняться... Потом просто "вставь" эту часть в блок. Т.о. ты избежишь повторений.

Comment: @ksa большое спасибо

Comment: И всё-таки лучше использовать CSS-классы, а не прямо прописывать стили в разметке.